# How to change Date Picker for IRAN in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, persian-calendar

I want to using ***UIDatePicker*** for **Persian(Farsi)** with **Shamsi** calendar.
My locale is **Asia/Tehran**.
I am using **Objective C** and **iOS9**.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**
Hello

Now you can download this *sample project* and use it:
**https://github.com/reza-khalafi/DatePicker/tree/master**

***Be Successful***

Answer (score 3):

Set Calendar of the datepicker as below

```
datePicker.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier:NSCalendarIdentifierPersian)!
```

For Objective C

```
datepicker.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierPersian];
```

Comment: _datePicker.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierPersian];

Comment: You are Welcome Brother.

Comment: @WaqarKhalid my app is crashing on `datepicker.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierPersian];` this line.

Comment: reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'